# Git hash search engine

Tags: git, github, search-engine

Given a Git commit hash, where I, for some reason, do not know what project it comes from, how can I figure that out? Note that I do not necessarily have the corresponding repository locally on my computer.

I tried regular search engines (Google) and code search engines ([Ohloh Code search](http://code.ohloh.net/)), but they do not provide reliable results. Also Github does not seem to provide this directly.

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Comment: Yes, but it does not seem to be good at indexing git hashes; and might not know about the specialities of them, e.g. referencing them by prefix. Something dedicated would work better, I presume.

Comment: There actually was such a hash search engine created a few years back as a project by an American university. By the time I found it, the project was already abandoned, which seems like a shame because it seems like a fun problem to work on. A bit of searching has not yielded a link, I'm afraid - the site was called something like 'GitBit' or something like that, and allowed you to look up blobs, trees, and commits by partial hash.

Comment: You are still asking to recommend a search engine

Comment: No, I’m asking for a way to figure out where the hash comes from. I also said what I tried so far (which happens to be search engines).